# search each string from my input files in all files in my directory using unix (grep or awk)

Tags: unix, awk, grep

Hi I'm new to this forum. Pls forgive me if I did not follow forum standard.
I have a file with below data

searchSTR.txt :

```
abc123
bac234
ret235
```

now I want to search each string from searchSTR.txt in all files in my directory 
I'm expecting below format of output

```
abc123 inventory.txt   
bac234 names.txt
```

(here abc123 search string found in invertory.txt file
      bac234 search string found in names.txt file)

please provide me solution using grep or awk
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
while read w; do
    for f in *; do
        grep -q "$w" "$f" && echo "$w $f"
    done
done  < searchSTR.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not give `grep -o -f` a try like this:

```
grep -o -f searchSTR.txt *sh
```

Comment: I'm not sure what version of grep I have but I have only following options for grep usage: grep [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-bhinsvwx] pattern [file...]